# Python/Selenium: element location is not correct

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am writing a Android app test script via Appium/Selenium by Python.
Sometimes the selenium reports wrong element location during test but the actual content is correct by visual check.

The app's layout is similar to this:

```
android.widget.LinearLayout[contains(@resource-id,'com.xxx/Iv1')]
android.widget.LinearLayout[contains(@resource-id,'com.xxx/Iv2')]
```

which the 'Iv1' is above the 'Iv2'

The code to check the error:

```
elem = temp['wd'].find_element_by_id("com.xxx/Iv1")
elem_LV = temp['wd'].find_element_by_id('com.xxx/Iv2')
while (elem.location['y'] > elem_LV.location['y']):
    logger.debug("e_Hide_Add_Toolbar: Misplace detected. Retry...")
    sleep(1)
```

Once selenium goes nuts, the location is always wrong with one second sleep waiting loop.

How do I recover from this situation?

================================================

More background and information about this issue

Clue #1:
Here is a debug log of coordinates

```
Nomral
Thu, 03 Mar 2016 18:46:28 - [DEBUG] - script.py[line:87] : elem y: 1008, elem x: 80
Thu, 03 Mar 2016 18:46:28 - [DEBUG] - script.py[line:88] : elem_LV y: 1118, elem_LV x: 120
Abnormal
Thu, 03 Mar 2016 18:50:23 - [DEBUG] - script.py[line:87] : elem y: 1168, elem x: 80
Thu, 03 Mar 2016 18:50:23 - [DEBUG] - script.py[line:88] : elem_LV y: 1118, elem_LV x: 120
```

There is a 160 pixels offset in abnormal one.

Clue #2:
The issue was found in a 10-inch Android 5 pad. 
However, it works fine in Nexus 7 which runs Android M when I am trying to double-check this issue on another device.

Answer (score 0):

So when you quote `elem.location[<coordinate axis>]` it returns you the coordinate value of the top left corner of the element(`elem` in your case).

Understanding the point that your  `'Iv1' is above the 'Iv2'`, you might want to compare their x-axis coordinates.
Since the **0,0 is your top left** corner of the device and x-axis extends right while y-axis extends down.
EDIT : Your code shall there by work :

```
while (elem.location['y'] > elem_LV.location['y']): 
    logger.debug("e_Hide_Add_Toolbar: Misplace detected. Retry...") 
    sleep(1)
```

Could you try and put a `wait` before you find the element and there loacation in the code.(To avoid getting there coordinates while they are loading)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, It should be that X-axis goes right and Y-axis goes down in the coordinate system.

Comment: Oh ya..my bad over there.

Comment: Waiting doesn't not help on this case. My guess is something relative to input method interaction. Different input methods generate different reproduce rate but none of them is stable enough on my device. 
Manual coordinate calculation is used as workaround for now.